# CSS Border with a botton

Tags: css

Can I achieve a custom CSS border with a button at one end which looks like this
*Without url(some image link)*?

***Note: I want so because when I want to change color, I have to manipulate image.***

[image]

I have achieved using image [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9rxu3n9/2/)

```
#stretch {
    border-image: url(http://akitech.org/img/border.png) 30 30 stretch;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use CSS pseudo-elements to create the decoration (the circle at the left) and to mask the chamfer at the right of the border (the angle at which the `border-right` would otherwise meet):

```
div {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    /* this property has to be set to change the border-color: */
    border-bottom-color: #f90;
}

/* common shared styles: */
div::before,
div::after {
    /* to ensure the pseudo-elements are rendered: */
    content: '';
    /* for positioning: */
    position: absolute;
    /* positioning the element with its uppermost edge
       against the bottom of the element, against the
       upper side of the bottom-border: */
    top: 100%;
    /* again, set to change the color of the ends: */
    background-color: #f90;
}
div::before {
    /* position against the left edge: */
    left: 0;
    /* move the pseudo element 10px up, and
       10px left: */
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    /* making the pseudo-element a circle: */
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/* masking the chamfer of the border-bottom's
   right-most edge: */
div::after {
    left: 100%;
    /* making the height/width the same width
       as the border itself: */
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f90;
}
div::before {
  left: 0;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div::after {
  left: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stretch">Here, the image is stretched to fill the area.</div>
```

In order to have these borders adapt to the length of the text, either the elements you want to have custom-bordered must themselves be able to contract to the width of the text, either using `float`:

```
div {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom-color: #f90;
    padding-left: 20px;
    /* forces the element to take up only that space required by
       its (non-floated) contents: */
    float: left;
    /* forces the floated elements to the next line: */
    clear: left;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f90;
}
div::before {
  left: 0;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div::after {
  left: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<div>longer text</div>
<div>much longer text</div>
<div>much much much longer text</div>
```

Or, possibly more simply, use `display: inline-block`:

```
div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f90;
}
div::before {
  left: 0;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div::after {
  left: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<div>longer text</div>
<div>much longer text</div>
<div>much much much longer text</div>
```

Or `display: inline` (these don't automatically force new-lines between elements, obviously):

```
div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-color: #f90;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f90;
}
div::before {
  left: 0;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div::after {
  left: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<div>longer text</div>
<div>much longer text</div>
<div>much much much longer text</div>
```

Comment: :) very nice css drawing learned from u, one question left is it possible to autostrech the shape below according to the upper text length in a simpler css way? in all these demos container is fixed width, i supposed just now the 'tika' is asking me to auto align the shape width along with the changing text without changing the fixed width in css. @David Thomas

Comment: the meaning of my question is like in fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/a9z1kyx7/

Comment: @BOBO: sorry for the wait, but I think I've addressed the question you raised (in the last three code-blocks and snippets)?

Answer (score 0):

**summary:** 
for simplist way to this question, should not using svg, pure css can draw the shape author expected very well cause it's a combination of cycle(border radius)+rect(thicker line), let's refer to the David's answer should be the easiest and most clean way to draw that shape under text.

//below is my debugging history and tries (i searched out many ways to approach it);
//though not good answers
I use background css attribute (not OP wanted) Op used border-image also valid.

```
<div class="custom-border" >SOME TEXT HERE</div>
<style>
    .custom-border{
   padding-left:20px;
   width:200px;  
   background:url(http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140224040010/shantae/images/b/bc/HGH_border_bottom.png) 0px 5px no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
height:150px;    
}
</style>
```

later I realized OP might dislike using image traditional way, I re understand the 
question is asking how to draw that shape in pure css and place it under the text and the responsive should be as flexible as the traditional way the svg shape will auto strech with the text placed on it.

after that, I've find some way to generate svg and place under text 
see if it works for no image solution or you can get it improved based on fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/hsfxS/1464/

during the process, i've found this useful tool of generating svg from below reference url: http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html

But the flaw is it's still a fixed width solution, the line svg won't auto stretch.

Have found a unclean way to improve auto stretch though not in pure css responsive way. 
but auto strech can be done by dynamically change below line

```
<rect stroke="#ff0000" id="svg_2" height="8" width="100%" y="27" x="40" stroke-width="5" fill="#FF0000"/>
```

where width="100%" or fixed value  => width="function return value"; //
// during this try, i found a little bug, jquery seems unable to select svg or element inside svg? however svg element tag attribute can be written in backend languge so still valid.

//3.44
Another way without touching the inner "rect' element below "svg" tag,  is to add a container to the whole thing, and using function to dynamically 
assign width for the container; 
like my attempt in this

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/hsfxS/1468/

so at least the width can be dynamically calculated out by a function to calculate the text length of the upper text so the line will be able to strech if the calculation is accurate enough.  There could be other ways to do svg auto strech with the text using pure css if other ppl find it.

Thanks.

5.02// since the author didn't say how complex the content is inside the container, 
I've created a demo in pure css triggered effct --- auto strech the shape along with the text above it in below fiddle. but i said it sure has many limitations though looks similar.

http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/a9z1kyx7/

my upper fiddle is only able to align correctly for singleline auto strech

I'm wondering if complex content (more than one line, there maybe a lot of block,inline mixed tag element inside which increases complexity for alignment) can also use css to do such decoration width auto adjustment without touching javascript or backend language.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use a background URL.

Comment: His question explicitly states that he does not want to use an image url. From the question: 'Without url(some image link)?'

Comment: I forgot to show jsFiddle. But, I have achieved that using image. When you want to change color, you have to manipulate the image, Boring!

Comment: yup i see that tika you mean the text increased but svg still fixed width,the one i created are only on fixed view. honestly, I'm also new to svg, don't know how well it supports responsive, image solution is the classical way to meet responsive.let's see if we can figure out that in svg. ;)

Comment: so @tika, do you mean the wapper shape should be auto increasing and decresing when the text changed like in this demo i created but in traditional css. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/a9z1kyx7/